# SQL Server function for order of data type

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, user-defined-types

I am looking for a way to change the natural order of a column (byte[8]) by implementing an ordering function which defines a new natural order on a data type.

Is it possible to define such a function for this or any other data type?

Edit:

What I am looking for is a way to specify an ordering function for a specific user defined data type, so that the natural order to the data type is given by this function.

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY udt-column`
gives me the selection sorted by the natural order of the udt without specifying an ordering function.

Also if I build a clustered index on a column of this udt the order should be by this function.

Comment: You just define this function and use it in an `ORDER BY` clause: `SELECT  mycolumn FROM mytable ORDER BY custom_order(mycolumn)`. Is it what you were asking?

Comment: You can also order by a CASE WHEN... as well, if that helps

Comment: @Quassnoi: I guess that is it. I did not know that this was possible. Do you have a link for documentation of this?

Comment: @caldis: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189499.aspx